# .htaccess file did not apply (removing .php extension)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried only remove the .php extension by using the .htaccess file on my XAMPP localhost server. I put the following lines into it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews
## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have tried more options to accomplish my goal, but nothing changed. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: And on which line should I put this line? If I put it on first, it causes Error 500 - Server Error.

Comment: This is what I have and it's working for me. I didn't have to allow override  `Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php `

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work for me.

Comment: Which URL you are working that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `AllowOverride All` in the **httpd.conf** file (the configuration file for apache). If you are using XAMPP on Windows, then the httpd.conf file should reside in a directory like :
C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Add the `AllowOverride All` line in the Directory tag. For example:

`<Directory C:\xampp\htdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

P.S. By allowing override you tell the server to allow the `.htaccess` file to override the default configuration of the server.

Edit: Sorry that I previously mentioned AllowOverride 'On'. It should be AllowOverride 'All'. This works fine in my ubuntu. I'll try to find out how to make it work in windows(xampp) soon.

Comment: I have following: AllowOverride All. After changing to AllowOverride On, nothing happend.

Comment: `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

This is the section of the httpd.conf file that makes the .htaccess(the same one as you posted) work. You should restart the server when you make changes to the config file. And, your .htaccess file should be kept in the same directory as the php files.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on apache2.  Hopefully it will work on XAMPP as well.
This is nearly the same as your code, but it checks that the requested filename *doesn't exist*, and that the PHP file *does* exist.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews
## hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php [NC,L]
```